# Not showing updated roles for discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have tried many times to get this to work. I believe the logic I am using works. I tried to print out the role names in the console but it would not be up to date to the roles that I set. I was sending messages in the discord server, but for testing, I just sent them to the terminal. This program is supposed to send a message anytime someone joins the role "1".

```
import discord, os, time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

load_dotenv()
_token = os.getenv('_token')
_server = os.getenv('_server')



found = False
_break = False
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    _channel = client.get_channel(int(1234567890))
    print(f"RoleCheck has connected to {client.guilds[0].name}")#await _channel.send(f"RoleCheck has connected to {client.guilds[0].name}")
    while True:
        BeforeRole = []
        AfterRole = []
        for member in client.guilds[0].members:
            for role in member.roles:
                if role.name == "1":
                    BeforeRole.append(member.name)


        time.sleep(10)
        for member in client.guilds[0].members:
            for role in member.roles:
                print(f"After: {role.name, member.name}")
                if role.name == "1":
                    AfterRole.append(member.name)

        if len(BeforeRole) < len(AfterRole):
            for name in BeforeRole:
                if _break:
                    break
                for _name in AfterRole:
                    if name !=_name:
                        print(f"{_name} has joined rank 1!")
                        break
                        found = True
                        _break = True
                    elif name == _name:
                        print("We are good")
                if _break:
                    break
            _break = False
            if not found:
                print(f"{_name[-1]} has joined rank 1!")
                found = True
        print(BeforeRole, AfterRole)
client.run(_token)
```

Comment: You may need to refresh the cache so re-fetch the channel or guild

Comment: Refresh what cache. My text editor? Or my browser?

Comment: Your clients cache. Changes are not instantly reflected from discord on your client, you need to sometimes fetch the new changes

Comment: Also. instead  if iterating over all members, You can simply get the role and iterate over `role.members`

Comment: This should really be answer but furthermore. You can use https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update to catch when the members gets a new role etc

Comment: yeah using await fetch_roles() worked thanks guys

Comment: you can make a answer for that